# Need query to find all records in Table1 that have multiple matches in Table2

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables, `Request` and `Action` which are joined by the field request_id.

Here's a quick data sample:

```
Request
request_id    group
100           My Group Name
101           My Group Name
102           My Group Name

Action
request_id    action_id    username
100           10           JDOE
100           11           ASMITH
101           12           SMILLER
102           13           CBROWN
```

I need to get a list of all requests along with the action_id and username that have more than one action. Here's what I have currently, but it lists all requests that have one ore more action.

So the result should show:

```
request_id    action_id    username
100           10           JDOE
100           11           ASMITH
```

The following works to select what I need, but I'm not sure how to work the request_id > 1 into it:

```
SELECT request.request_id, action.action_id, action.username
FROM request RIGHT JOIN action ON request.request_id = action.request_id
WHERE (((request.group)="My Group Name"))
GROUP BY request.request_id, action.action_id, action.username;
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: If you add HAVING COUNT(Action.Request_id) > 1 does that give you what you want?

Comment: That gives 0 requests. Do I need to SELECT action.request_id first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT 
Action.request_id, 
Action.action_id, Action.username
FROM [Action] 
INNER JOIN Request ON Action.request_id = Request.request_id
WHERE Action.request_id In (
  SELECT request_id FROM action Group By Request_Id 
  HAVING Count(request_id)>1)
AND Request.group="My Group Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `having` clause.  This is like a `where` clause, but on aggregated columns:

```
SELECT request.request_id, action.action_id, action.username
FROM request RIGHT JOIN
     action
     ON request.request_id = action.request_id
WHERE (((request.group)="My Group Name"))
GROUP BY request.request_id, action.action_id, action.username
having counte(request.request_id) > 1
```

Comment: should `counters` be `COUNT`?